# Karma test runner not picking up Enzyme test files within a component's sub-directory

Tags: reactjs, debugging, karma-runner, chai, enzyme

I'm testing my React project with Enzyme (testing utility) using Chai's Expect library and running the test using Karma (test runner).

My working project directory structure looks like this:
app -> components -> Button -> __test -> test.jsx

Karma has no problem finding the tests above and runs successfully.

The directory structure in question looks like this:
app -> components -> List -> ListHeader -> __test -> test.jsx

Karma does not pick up the tests if they reside within a sub directory of a component.

I've set `autoWatch=true`, added paths in `karma.config` and looked for clues/hints/solution on the internet, without luck. I've added my `karma.config` file if it helps at all.

Thanks for taking the time to look into this problem!

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const argv = require('yargs').argv
const path = require('path')

const aliases = require('./webpack/alias')
const config = require('./webpack/settings')
const loaders = require('./webpack/loaders')
const preloaders = require('./webpack/preloaders')

const karmaConfig = (config) => {
  config.set({
    // only use PhantomJS for our 'test' browser
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    // just run once by default unless --watch flag is passed
    singleRun: !argv.watch,

    // Enable or disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // which karma frameworks do we want integrated
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],

    // displays tests in a nice readable format
    reporters: ['spec'],

    // include some polyfills for babel and phantomjs
    files: [
      './node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
      './node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
      './app/**/**/__test/test.jsx', // specify files to watch for tests
      './app/**/**/__test/test.js', // specify files to watch for tests
      './app/**/**/**/__test/test.jsx', // specify files to watch for tests
      './app/**/**/**/__test/test.js' // specify files to watch for tests
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      // these files we want to be precompiled with webpack
      // also run tests throug sourcemap for easier debugging
      ['./app/**/**/__test/*']: ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },
    // A lot of people will reuse the same webpack config that they use
    // in development for karma but remove any production plugins like UglifyJS etc.
    // I chose to just re-write the config so readers can see what it needs to have
    webpack: {
       devtool: 'inline-source-map',
       resolve: {
        // allow us to import components in tests like:
        // import Example from 'components/Example';
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, './app'),

        // allow us to avoid including extension name
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],

        // required for enzyme to work properly
        alias: aliases
      },

      module: {
        // don't run babel-loader through the sinon module
        noParse: [
          /sinon(\\|\/)pkg(\\|\/)sinon\.js/
        ],
        // run babel loader for our tests
        // preLoaders: preloaders,
        loaders: loaders,
      },
      // required for enzyme to work properly
      externals: {
        'jsdom': 'window',
        'cheerio': 'window',
        'react-dom/server': 'window',
        'text-encoding': 'window',
        'react/addons': true,
        'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
        'react/lib/ReactContext': 'window'
      },
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
      stats: {
        colors: true,
        chunks: false
      }
    },
    // tell karma all the plugins we're going to be using to prevent warnings
    plugins: [
      'karma-*'
    ],

    autoWatch: true
  })
}

module.exports = karmaConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in globbing:

> In the end the main cause seemed to be if i used a glob pattern in the karma.config which contained a double asterisk (*/) in a folder that went further than a second level deep.
>
> Then managed to replicate the error by using the node-glob directly, to generate the same error.
>
> In the end, using the glob.sync route, and building the URL array myself worked around the issue. Hopefully this gives the author a clue into what he can do to fix. Cheers

Use jsdom and glob as an alternative. For example:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const chai = require('chai');

global.document = jsdom.jsdom();
global.window = document.defaultView;

global.navigator = window.navigator || {};
global.Node = window.Node;
global.addEventListener = window.addEventListener;
global.MouseEvent = window.MouseEvent;
global.KeyboardEvent = window.KeyboardEvent;
global.Event = window.Event;
global.btoa = window.btoa;
global.FormData = window.FormData;
global.FileReader = window.FileReader;
global.File = window.File;

window.beforeEach = global.beforeEach;
window.afterEach = global.afterEach;
window.before = global.before;
window.after = global.after;
window.mocha = true;
```

**References**

- [Use glob.sync to loadFiles with angular2 Workaround for https://githu… · FountainJS/generator-fountain-karma@3213e61](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-karma/commit/3213e61ddf92337521b570f94caafbbed2258064)
- [ENFILE: file table overflow with Karma · Issue #1979 · karma-runner/karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1979)
- [isaacs/node-glob: glob functionality for node.js](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)
- [Testing ReactJS components with mocha-webpack – mmontoya – Medium](https://medium.com/@mmontoya/testing-reactjs-components-with-mocha-webpack-ce7f710d268c)
- [Unit and Functional Testing React Components – ReactJS News](https://reactjsnews.com/testing-in-react)
- [Fast Unit Test With Reactjs](http://dev.cravefood.services/2017/01/13/fast-unit-test-with-reactjs.html)
- [Angular without Karma](https://kasperlewau.github.io/post/angular-without-karma/)
- [Automated testing with Headless Chrome  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai)